# eslint does not respect indent for class properties

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to enable a 4 space lint rule for my reactjs project but the rule is being ignored or behaving unusually when I use properties in a class.  But the rule works on class methods. Here is my eslint file:

```
env:
  browser: true,
  node: true,
extends:
  - 'airbnb-base'
  - 'eslint:recommended'
  - 'plugin:react/recommended'
parser: 'babel-eslint'
parserOptions:
  ecmaFeatures:
    jsx: true
  ecmaVersion: 12
  sourceType: module
rules: {
  ...etc...
  "indent": ["error", 4],
  "no-tabs": 0,
  ...etc...
}
```

To demonstrate the problem, I made a file called `src/Test.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
export default
@observer
class Test extends React.Component {
  @observable processes = {
      testMode: '',
  }

  @observable other = {
      testMode: '',
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div id="app">{this.testMode}</div>
      );
  }
}
```

Notice how there is only two spaces in front of each `@observable` word.  When I run the command `node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix src/Test.js` (henceforth the **lint command**), no changes are made to my `src/Test.js` file.

However, I noticed some interesting scenarios:

**SCENARIO 1: first property experiment**

If I start line 7 with 3 spaces like this    `@observable processes = {`, running the **lint command** will change the indents on line 8 and line 9 from 6 spaces to 7 spaces.  This is the final result:

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
export default
@observer
class Test extends React.Component {
   @observable processes = {
       testMode: '',
   }

  @observable other = {
      testMode: '',
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div id="app">{this.testMode}</div>
      );
  }
}
```

**SCENARIO 2: second property experiment**

If I start line 11 with 3 spaces like this    `@observable other = {`, running the **lint command** will change the indents on line 12 to line 19 from 6 spaces to 7 spaces.  This is the final result:

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
export default
@observer
class Test extends React.Component {
  @observable processes = {
      testMode: '',
  }

   @observable other = {
       testMode: '',
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div id="app">{this.testMode}</div>
       );
   }
}
```

**SCENARIO 3: @observable resets other spaces**

If I start line 15 with 3 spaces like this    `render() {`, running the **lint command** will undo all my changes on Test.js

**SCENARIO 4: Successful Lint When Zero @observable**

I changed my `src/Test.js` to this:

```
import React from 'react';
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div id="app">{this.testMode}</div>
      );
  }
}
```

Running the **lint command**, properly indents everything with the 4 space rule.

**QUESTION**

How do I get the eslinter to respect 4 space indentation when there are properties in my class?

---

**UPDATE**

I updated my question.  Initially I thought the issue was related to `@observable` decorator.  But I have since discovered the issue happens any time there is a property in my class.  Indents rule is enforced on class methods, but not class properties.  How do I get indent rule to apply both methods and properties?

Comment: How did u solve the issue ?